# how to ignore fieldname while marshalling/unmarshalling java object

Tags: java, marshalling, unmarshalling, xstream

I've got the following problem and I've no clue how to solve this.

I've got a list of different types of points based on a common interface.
I am using Java XStream to marshall and unmarshall those classes.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    List<IPoint> listOfPoint = new ArrayList<IPoint>();
    listOfPoint.add(new PointTypeA(0.1));
    listOfPoint.add(new PointTypeB(0.2));
    listOfPoint.add(new PointTypeA(0.3));
    PointSet ps = new PointSet(1, listOfPoint);

    XStream xstream = new XStream(new StaxDriver());
    xstream.processAnnotations(PointTypeA.class);
    xstream.processAnnotations(PointTypeB.class);
    xstream.processAnnotations(PointSet.class);

    String xml = xstream.toXML(ps);
    System.out.println(xml);
}
```

When I print my objects in XML format I get the following result:

```
<set id="1">
  <typeA>
    <xCoordinate>0.1</xCoordinate>
  </typeA>
  <typeB>
    <xCoordinate>0.2</xCoordinate>
  </typeB>
  <typeA>
    <xCoordinate>0.3</xCoordinate>
  </typeA>
</set>
```

But instead of the result above, I want to have the following output:

```
<set id="1">
  <typeA>0.1</typeA>
  <typeB>0.2</typeB>
  <typeA>0.3</typeA>
</set>
```

What I want is not to have tags like `<xCoordinate>`, but I want their value to be stored under the classname's tag.
I do not want to ignore the value of xCoordinate field, but I want to to have an "inline value".
Is it possible to do that?
I've tried converters with no success, and I've got no idea how to solve this.

My classes are:

```
public interface IPoint {

    int getSomeInformation();
}  

@XStreamAlias("set")
public class PointSet {

    @XStreamAsAttribute
    private int id;

    @XStreamImplicit
    private List<IPoint> points;

    public PointSet(int id, List<IPoint> points) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.points = points;
    }
}

@XStreamAlias("typeA")
public class PointTypeA implements IPoint {

    private double xCoordinate;

    public PointTypeA(double d) {
        super();
        this.xCoordinate = d;
    }
}

@XStreamAlias("typeB")
public class PointTypeB implements IPoint {

    private double xCoordinate;

    public PointTypeB(double d) {
        super();
        this.xCoordinate = d;
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't know how XStream works at all, but usually in Java you use the keyword "transient" to indicate that the variable shall not automatically be stored/retrieved.
Do not mix it up with "volatile" btw, that indicates the variable to be read-through and write-through in terms of caching.

Answer (score 0):

Converter for your point class is rather simple.

```
public static class CoordConverter implements Converter
{
    public boolean canConvert(Class clazz)
    {
        return PointTypeA.class == clazz;
    }

    public void marshal(Object object, HierarchicalStreamWriter hsw, MarshallingContext mc)
    {
        PointTypeA obj = (PointTypeA) object;
        hsw.setValue(String.valueOf(obj.xCoordinate));
    }

    public Object unmarshal(HierarchicalStreamReader hsr, UnmarshallingContext uc)
    {
        double val = Double.parseDouble(hsr.getValue());
        PointTypeA obj = new PointTypeA(val);
        return obj;
    }
}
```

You can register it with

```
xstream.registerConverter(new CoordConverter());
```

Of course, this converter is valid for `PointTypeA` class but you can easily extend above code for other classes you need and/or write more generalized version.